# Why JSON::Builder not using `with obj yield` modifier?

Tags: crystal-lang

Crystal allows to use `with` keyword to improve DSL.

But in its standard library it's not used for JSON::Builder, the example from docs looks like that:

```
JSON.build do |json|
  json.object do
    json.field "name", "foo"
  end
end
```

While it could be written shorter as:

```
JSON.build do
  object do
    field "name", "foo"
  end
end
```

So, why it's not implemented in such way? **Are there any drawbacks** of using `with xxx yield`?

Possible implementation

```
class JSON
  def self.build
    with JSON.new yield
  end

  def object
    builder = JSONObject.new
    with builder yield self
    p builder.result
  end

  class JSONObject
    getter :result
    @result = Hash(String, String).new
    def field(key : String, value : String)
      @result[key] = value
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in many cases you want to pass a builder to another method, and there's no way to refer to `self` inside `with ... yield.`

Additionally, `JSON::Builder` isn't used that frequently so it's not a big difference to have to write a few more characters now and then.

Comment: To support the passing around reason: `JSON.build` hardly forms a domain specific language. It's just a regular API and can be integrated with other APIs and custom implementations.